# mysql_install_db - How to access the MySQL after installation?

Tags: mysql

I've installed the mysql 5.6 for a poc purpose.

After install using mysql_install_db, how to access it (when not using the --random-passwords option)?

Here is what mysql_install_db says:

```
[root@mysqlen1 scripts]# ./mysql_install_db --defaults-file=/tmp/my2.cnf --basedir=/usr/local/mysql-5.6.41-linux-glibc2.12-x86_64 --datadir=/dados2/ --user=mysql
Installing MySQL system tables...2023-09-06 11:03:02 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2023-09-06 11:03:02 0 [Note] Ignoring --secure-file-priv value as server is running with --bootstrap.
2023-09-06 11:03:02 0 [Note] /usr/local/mysql-5.6.41-linux-glibc2.12-x86_64/bin/mysqld (mysqld 5.6.41) starting as process 3684 ...
OK

Filling help tables...2023-09-06 11:03:04 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2023-09-06 11:03:04 0 [Note] Ignoring --secure-file-priv value as server is running with --bootstrap.
2023-09-06 11:03:04 0 [Note] /usr/local/mysql-5.6.41-linux-glibc2.12-x86_64/bin/mysqld (mysqld 5.6.41) starting as process 3706 ...
OK

To start mysqld at boot time you have to copy
support-files/mysql.server to the right place for your system

PLEASE REMEMBER TO SET A PASSWORD FOR THE MySQL root USER !
To do so, start the server, then issue the following commands:

  /usr/local/mysql-5.6.41-linux-glibc2.12-x86_64/bin/mysqladmin -u root password 'new-password'
  /usr/local/mysql-5.6.41-linux-glibc2.12-x86_64/bin/mysqladmin -u root -h mysqlen1 password 'new-password'

Alternatively you can run:

  /usr/local/mysql-5.6.41-linux-glibc2.12-x86_64/bin/mysql_secure_installation
```

But `/usr/local/mysql-5.6.41-linux-glibc2.12-x86_64/bin/mysqladmin -u root password 'new-password'` does not work.

```
[root@mysqlen1 bin]# ./mysqladmin --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql2.sock -uroot password 'test123'
./mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)'
```

Also `mysql_secure_installation` does not work.

```
[root@mysqlen1 bin]# /usr/local/mysql-5.6.41-linux-glibc2.12-x86_64/bin/mysql_secure_installation --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql2.sock



NOTE: RUNNING ALL PARTS OF THIS SCRIPT IS RECOMMENDED FOR ALL MySQL
      SERVERS IN PRODUCTION USE!  PLEASE READ EACH STEP CAREFULLY!

In order to log into MySQL to secure it, we'll need the current
password for the root user.  If you've just installed MySQL, and
you haven't set the root password yet, the password will be blank,
so you should just press enter here.

Enter current password for root (enter for none):
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Happily, I've found the parameter `--random-passwords` for `mysql_install_db` which generate a random password. Also, there is `--skip-grant-tables` option.

Without the `--random-passwords`, the only option is to use `--skip-grant-tables` with `mysqld_safe` and then reset the password? Is this the "right" way or I am missing something else?